# Typescript interfaces and promise return an object/constructor?

Tags: typescript, promise

I have a Promise which returns a type

### person.ts

```
const personFactory: PersonFactory = (name, lastName) => ({ speak: () => console.log(`${name}:${lastName}`); });
const personPromise: Promise<PersonFactory | null> = Promise.resolve().then(function handler() { return personFactory });

export const loadPerson = (): Promise<PersonFactory | null> => {
  return personPromise;
};
```

### index.ts

```
declare global {
  interface Metaverse {
    Person?: PersonFactory;
  }
}

export interface PersonClient {
    speak: (args: string) => void;
}

export type PersonFactory = (firstName: string, lastName: string) => PersonClient;
```

person.ts and index.ts are packaged up and put into npm package.

### test ts project - index.ts

```
import { loadPerson } from '@person/library';

const load = async () => {
  const person = await loadPerson();

  if (person) {
    person('drag13', 'developer').speak('something');
  }
}

load()
```

// or

```
(async function() {
 let person = await loadPerson();
 person("drag13", "developer").speak("this===is===a===message")
})()
```

-- Update

I used Drag13's example and packaged it up into an npm. When I call loadPerson, the console prints out the string in speak.

However there is a typescript error which says

```
TS2349: This expression is not callable. Type 'PersonFactory' has no call signatures.
```

Comment: `Promise.resolve().then(() => { console.log("Hello World") });` does not result in a `PersonFactory`

Comment: Could you please put cursos to the `loadPerson` and hit F12. I am curious about the type
or, give the link to the library

Comment: Seems to be ok now, maybe I had something cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined that your promise should `return` factory or null. However in your code you are not returning anything.

The correct version will be look like this:

```
const personPromise: Promise<PersonFactory | null> = Promise.resolve().then(() => () => ({ speak: () => null }));
```

Now you can use this like this:

```js
(async function () {

    interface PersonClient {
        speak: (args: string) => void;
    }

    type PersonFactory = (firstName: string, lastName: string) => PersonClient;
    const personFactory: PersonFactory = (name, lastName) => ({ speak: () => `${name}:${lastName}` });
    const personPromise: Promise<PersonFactory | null> = Promise.resolve().then(function handler() { return personFactory });

    const person = await personPromise;

    if (person) {
        person('drag13', 'developer').speak('something');
    }

})()
```

To make it works we:

- defined function `personFactory`
- returned `personFactory` from the `then`

Now it works - [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/BQQwzgngdgxgBAMwK6wC4EsD2U7AJRwDeAUMXOXOlKgKYBOCIMNcACvWNgMIA26N1ImQoiwABxogA1gC5cIOgHMwcsKjpVFBALwA%20OADdM6ACYBuYeQC%20pEaggS2HbADEmqTHQhxtuBOjo1ADkQAFsaVXVNABo4HnBUEPDIjSgtH312QO4%20AVQLERhsNTgJbKg3GA8vOSzOCvdPb19gKDCaWPjg9p19YEI4cUlZXF64AAMAEkI28KsZaa7E9qtxuCs8AooiqBKy%20tY6TFD0MAi2I5OzgB4610avOAAfOCgkHh59X0Pj05oAOjoNE4PAMNHw-1QAAsBMBkGgsDgoSAoCYePR8EQ4EDUEg6Dh9vcqk11ptbNtiqhSs4cL4QAB3EDoKmEqA-K40CyWSgIXCsggkEQiVnAADkJjoIEUAEYAMyi2LimhgniYMqivD-IbSMWccLQzQarbWUgbfBAA)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what "then(() => () => ({ speak: () => null }))" does. Can this be simplified?

Comment: Let's make it explicit @fes - see updates

Comment: i did speak: () => console.log(`${name}:{lastName}`); which prints out in the console but I get this TS warning.

"This expression is not callable. Type 'PersonFactory' has no call signatures."

Comment: @fes please update the question with the relevant code. I've put the link to the playground - there is no error right now

Comment: I updated the original post. I don't know why there is that Typescript issue even though the speak method is called.